# Syntax for Sparql query for pages with specific infobox

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I'm trying Sparql for the first time (on dbpedia) and can't get any queries to work.  Everything I try returns a syntax error or an empty dataset.

For example, I tried the queries on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353537/sparql-exact-match-regex).  They didn't work, so I made the following changes:
- I read that wikiPageUsesTemplate has changed to http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageUsesTemplate,
- I add 'WHERE' to select statement, though I guess that must be optional,
- I reduced the whole thing to a minimum: just the infobox clause.

But it still doesn't work!  Here is what I came up with:

```
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>

SELECT * WHERE {
    ?page dbo:wikiPageUsesTemplate
        <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Template:Infobox_artist>
}
LIMIT 100
```

I have been trying my queries [here](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/).

Comment: "They didn't work"  What didn't work about them?  If you're getting syntax errors, then try running your queries through [sparql.org's validator](http://sparql.org/query-validator.html).  By the way, when I tried your query at the SNORQL interface that you linked to, the error message I get is "
The web-site you are currently trying to access is under maintenance at this time. 
We are sorry for any inconvenience this has caused."  That has nothing to do with a problem in the query.  That's not the issue you're having, right?

Comment: I get the 'under maintenance' message sometimes - it seems to come and go.  My issue with the above query is that i get an empty result set, which i believe is not correct.  I will try that validator when i get home.  Thx

Comment: I ran my sample query above through the validator - is seemed to pass - and tried its reformatted version but I still get an empty result set.

Comment: And why do you think that that's the wrong result?  Find a wikipedia page that uses the template.  Then go to its corresponding DBpedia resource page.  Do you see any mention of the template?

Comment: No, I do not see the name of the info box listed as a property of the target dbpedia pages.  More evidence of your conclusion below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using `dbpedia-owl:wikiPageUsesTemplate`.  According to http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Datasets39/Properties (emphasis added):

> http://xx.dbpedia.org/property/wikiPageUsesTemplate (**may be**
>   changed to http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageUsesTemplate in
>   **future releases**)

I'm not whether the current data in DBpedia is a future release (in terms of that document), but it sounds like you should still be on the old property.  It's easy enough to test this, though.  Since you have a query language and a webservice, it's quite easy to try a more general result as a sort of sanity check.  In particular, something like the following very strongly suggests that it's not the property you want.

```
SELECT *  WHERE {
  ?s <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageUsesTemplate> ?o         
}
LIMIT 100
```

[SPARQL results (0 results)](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20%2a%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?s%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageUsesTemplate%3E%20?o%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0ALIMIT%20100&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Similarly, since you've got an interactive endpoint, why not try seeing what properties *do* relate things to `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Template:Infobox_artist>`, and by what properties?

```
SELECT distinct ?p  WHERE {
  ?s ?p <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Template:Infobox_artist>      
}
limit 500
```

[SPARQL results (2 results)](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20distinct%20?p%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?s%20?p%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Template%3aInfobox_artist%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%20500&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

The two results are

```
http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRedirects
```

More queries can show us what redirects to it.  It turns out that it's just

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Template:Infobox_Artist
```

As it turns out, though, nothing is related to that either.

```
SELECT * WHERE {
   ?s ?p <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Template:Infobox_Artist>
}
limit 500
```

[SPARQL results (0 results)](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20%2a%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20?s%20?p%20%3Chttp://dbpedia.org/resource/Template%3aInfobox_Artist%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%20500&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

It doesn't look like DBpedia is actually recording the information that you're looking for.

Comment: To answer some of your questions... I tried the new form of wikiPageUsesTemplate because I couldn't get the old form to work. In the SO page I linked above 2 of the answers suggest ways to do the query - using the old form of wikiPageUsesTemplate - and trying either of them I still get empty result sets.  I believe that DBPedia used to support the sort of query I'm attempting (based on infobox type), but I accept your reasoning and conclusion that it does not any more.

Comment: When in doubt, look at the data. :)  I'm actually surprised that they have the vocabulary if they're not going to use it.  Perhaps it was in an older version, or maybe it's in a different, but parallel, dataset?